# Unable to use RenderRepaint on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to capture a snapshot from a widget, I'm doing exactly what the documentation said, but it always returns this error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you put `_key` in wrong place in your code `Stack`
That's why error show `type RenderStack is not a subtype of type RenderRepaintBoundary` 
You can move `_key` to `RepaintBoundary` 
You can change from

```
body: RepaintBoundary(
  child: Stack(
     key: _key,
```

to

```
body: RepaintBoundary(
  key: _key, 
  child: Stack(
```